# Unable to Install Windows Azure Active Directory Module - Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, azure

I'm facing a typical Microsoft bug whereby I am unable to install Windows Azure Active Directory Module Found here [Windows Azure AD for Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx)

Background:
I am Running Windows 7 with Service Pack 1.
Powershell 4.0  is currently installed.
Microsoft.Net Framework 3.5.1 is checked under programs and Features
Microsoft Online Services Sign-in Assistant Both Beta and non Beta versions were installed..PC rebooted and no luck with either of them.

[image]

[image]

[image: Windows Azure Active Directory Module for Windows Powershell. You must have Windows Powershell 2.0 or greater installed on this computer Problem]

I have read many posts online and none of them appeared to have helped.
Does anyone know how to overcome this annoying bug.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/tune_in_to_windows_intune/archive/2013/11/09/error-when-trying-to-install-windows-azure-active-directory-module-for-windows-powershell.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/aef5669a-bc46-4c7a-9cbd-d0ed781e5190/waad-wont-install-says-signin-assistant-needs-to-be-installed-but-it-already-is?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this from Erik who posted on this site.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/tune_in_to_windows_intune/archive/2013/11/09/error-when-trying-to-install-windows-azure-active-directory-module-for-windows-powershell.aspx

Run the command prompt as an administrator by holding shift + right click on the command prompt icon, then Run as administrator.

[image: Run the command prompt as administrator]
At the command prompt
Change directories to where you AdministrationConfig-En.msi is installed.

In the command prompt type:
 **msiexec /i AdministrationConfig-EN.msi**
It will now install without the powershell warning.

Erik's commentary is that the powershell settings are only readable when privileges are elevated.

The beta version of the sign-in assistant which also needs to be installed prior to the Administrationconfig didn't help me but have helped others.

It was definitely a long and painful process.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new beta version for the sign in assistant.  Look up the new beta version and it will work.  Just went through this about a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

A String Value is "missing" in the registry. There are two potential locations in the Windows registry where PowerShell versions are stored, depending on what version or versions you have installed or possibly installed in the past.

Older version location, including Version 1.0 and 2.0:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1

Later versions location, including 5.0 and others:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3

Each location has a sub-key called PowerShellEngine that contains a string value called PowerShellVersion.

If this value is missing in the first key mentioned above, you will receive the installation error because the installer does not look the in the second key mentioned above for the PS version.

If the value is missing, simply add it with the data of 2.0

Now installation of the AADRM will work assuming you have PS 2.0 or later installed and assuming you are using the installer version 2.50 or later of the AADRM, which does not require the sign-in assistant to be installed.